# Jquery Accordion on unordered list

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to do something like the below where my UL is collapsible but because the UL is generated from the ASP:Menu control I don't get an ID for the UL so I need to add the accordion to the class somehow. Does anyone know how to assign a Jquery effect to a class?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#accordion').accordion();
    })
</script>
<ul id="accordion">
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Generated code:

```
 <ul class="level1">
    <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
        <img src="/images/calculator.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" />Financial</a></li>
    <li><a class="level2 staticItem level2 selected" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;Menu1&#39;,&#39;4\\6&#39;)">Address</a></li>
    <li><a class="level3 staticItem level3" href="/Controls/Financial/AddressBook.aspx" target="_blank">Address Book</a></li>
    <li><a class="level3 staticItem level3" href="/Controls/Financial/CustomerTypes.aspx" target="_blank">Customer Types</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
        <img src="/images/container.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" />Container</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1 staticItem level1">
        <img src="/images/product.png" alt="" title="" class="icon" />Product</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('.className').accordion();`

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comment `$('.className').accordion();` will do the trick.

here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="myclass">
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h3><a href="#">header</a></h3>
     <div>
         Content goes here
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $(function(){
        $('.myclass').accordion();
    })
```

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhNjB/)

Comment: I have an issue where the desired effect is happening on the object but it is instantly reverting, I think because the page refreshes or posts back afterwards, how can i prevent that?

Comment: This is a postback problem. The issue appears because of `<a>` tags inside `<h3>` tags. Do you need this tags to lead somewhere?

Comment: Actually the code was for an example but my UL is dynamically created from the asp:menu control. There are no <h3> tags in there.

Comment: Ok i just added the markup. I got around the issue with the first level items by changing them to selectable=false because they are not actual links but cant do that for the both level2 or 3 because they are classed as child elements.

Comment: JqueryUI accordion doesn't work without `<h3>` elements and `<div>` after `<h3>`.